# OOP - about modeling Request/Response objects and entities

Tags: oop

I'm curious about what is the best (or the right) approach/pattern when you are modelling objects that have same structure between http requests, http response and objects handled by Service classes.

I have created a class to be parsed by request:

```
data class PersonRequest(
    val name: String,
    val qualities: Map<String, Any>
)
```

And I have created the response class:

```
data class PersonResponse(
    val name: String,
    val qualities: Map<String, Any>
)
```

And the object used in Services:

```
data class Person(
    val name: String,
    val qualities: Map<String, Any>
)
```

This code looks redundant to me and I'm not sure what is the best approach to avoid. Maybe extends Person on request and response?

Comment: The `Person` entity is independent from the http context.

Comment: We usually make an object for request, response and other for business layer but in this case doesn't make sense have 3 objects that are equals. Any suggestion?

Comment: The Response and Response classes are not related to the domain layer (the problem you are trying to solve), rather, they are related to the infrastructure layer .

Comment: Good point! I should create a common class in infrastructure layer and extend it, right?

Comment: something like that. if you are not just trying to learn, there are many frameworks that already solved these type of problems.

Comment: could you tell me any framework?

Comment: that depends on the language you are familiar with